# Return only results based on current object for dynamic menus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have an object that `has_many` - how would I go about getting back only the results that are related to the original results related ids?

Example:

tier_tbl

```
| id     | name
  1        low
  2        med
  3        high
```

randomdata_tbl

```
| id     | tier_id | name
  1        1         xxx
  2        1         yyy
  3        2         zzz
```

I would like to build a query that returns only, in the case of the above example, rows 1 and 2 from `tier_tbl`, because only 1 and 2 exist in the tier_id data.

Im new to activerecord, and without a loop, don't know a good way of doing this.  Does rails allow for this kind of query building in an easier way?

The reasoning behind this is so that I can list only menu items that relate to the specific object I am dealing with.  If the object i am dealing with has only the items contained in randomdata_tbl, there is no reason to display the 3rd tier name.  So i'd like to omit it completely.  I need to go this direction because of the way the models are set up.  The example im dealing with is slightly more complicated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets call your first table **tiers** and second table **randoms**

If **tier** has many **randoms** and you want to find all **tiers** whoes id present in table **randoms**, you can do it that way:

```
# database query only
Tier.joins(:randoms).uniq
```

or

```
  # with some ruby code
  Tier.select{ |t| t.randoms.any? }
```